# How can I create a WHERE clause where there are some mandatory fields and some other optional fields in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not so into database and I have the following doubt. I am using **MySql**

I have this query that return multiple records (it works fine) and I have to add the **WHERE** clause in such a way that some fields are mandatory and some other fields are optional.

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    EnutrifoodMessage.content
    , MessageType.message_type_name
    , Country.country_name
    , IFNULL(Province.province_name, 'All Provinces') as province_name
    , IFNULL(District.district_name, 'Any District') as district_name
    , Crop.crop_name
    , EnutriMessageDetails.creation_date
    , EnutriMessageDetails.message_important_days
    , temp_scale.scale_name as temperature
    , humidity_scale.scale_name as humidity
    , ProcessPhase.phase_name
    , ProcessPhaseAction.process_phase_action_name
    , Urgency.urgency_name as action
    , IFNULL(MeteoWarningDescription.meteo_warning_description_name, '') as emergency
    , IFNULL(EnutriMessageDetails.internal_link, '') as internal_link
    , IFNULL(EnutriMessageDetails.reference_link, '') as reference_link
    , IFNULL(EnutriMessageDetails.external_link, '') as external_link
    , IFNULL(cleared_by_institution.institution_name, '') as message_cleared_by
    , UserType.user_type_name as end_user
    , provider.institution_name as provider
    , ValueAddition.value_addition_name
FROM EnutriMessageDetails
LEFT JOIN EnutrifoodMessage
ON EnutrifoodMessage.id = EnutriMessageDetails.enutri_food_message_id
LEFT JOIN MessageType
ON MessageType.id = EnutriMessageDetails.message_type_id
LEFT JOIN Localization
ON Localization.id = EnutriMessageDetails.localization_id
LEFT JOIN Country
ON Country.id = Localization.country_id
LEFT JOIN Province
ON Province.id = Localization.province_id
LEFT JOIN District
ON District.id = Localization.district_id
LEFT JOIN Crop
ON Crop.id = EnutriMessageDetails.crop_id
LEFT JOIN Scale temp_scale
ON temp_scale.id = EnutriMessageDetails.temp_scale_id
LEFT JOIN Scale humidity_scale
ON humidity_scale.id = EnutriMessageDetails.humidity_scale_id
LEFT JOIN ProcessPhase
ON ProcessPhase.id = EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_id
LEFT JOIN ProcessPhaseAction
ON ProcessPhaseAction.id = EnutriMessageDetails.process_phase_action_id
LEFT JOIN Urgency
ON Urgency.id = EnutriMessageDetails.urgency_id
LEFT JOIN MeteoWarningDescription
ON MeteoWarningDescription.id = EnutriMessageDetails.meteo_warning_description_id
LEFT JOIN Institution cleared_by_institution
ON cleared_by_institution.id = EnutriMessageDetails.cleared_by_id
LEFT JOIN UserType
ON UserType.id = EnutriMessageDetails.user_type_id
LEFT JOIN Institution provider
ON provider.id = EnutriMessageDetails.provided_by_id
LEFT JOIN ValueAddition
ON ValueAddition.id = EnutriMessageDetails.value_addition_id
WHERE Localization.id = 2
AND Crop.id = 2
ORDER BY EnutrifoodMessage.id
```

I need to add the **WHERE** clause in such a way that:

1) This field is mandatory:

```
Localization.id = 2

UserType.id = 1
```

2) These other fields are optional:

```
EnutriMessageDetails.creation_date >= a specified date

Urgency.id = 3
```

I want that the first type of field have to be inserted, the other type have to be optional and can be not fill.

How can I correctly handle this situation?

Comment: When LEFT JOIN, add right side table conditions to the ON clause instead of the WHERE clause.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, so please dont shoot me if I am wrong, The LEFT join will return null data if the record does not exists witch makes it optional, so why not make the joins that you want to force INNERjoins? And combine it with what jarlh said.

Comment: @Renier no I want to have some fields that are mandatory in the where clause and some other where clause fields that are not mandatory (the user can left it blank so the query don't use these field in the where condition if are not fill)

Comment: O ok now I get it, It so the where clause should be dynamic, are you in control of the sql if you are you can just build the where dynamic with code? Thats an option or what I did in the past and not sure with dates but for example with a string I used  a like statment "  Like '%yourVARIABLE%'   " so when the user entered a value it would either filter it or if it is blank will return all. Not sure about dates..

Comment: Yes the WHERE clause should be dynamic. No I can't build dinamycally into the code (I mean it is not into a Java\PHP\whatever programming languange code). So I can't dynamically check if the parameter value is present and eventually add it. I ahve to do it directly into the query in some way

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`? Can you have an `EnutriMessageDetails` without a matching `MessageType` as your query suggests? That doesn't seem likely. So correct your query in the first step. Change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` where an outer join is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Try case expression:

```
Where  Localization.id = 2 and UserType.id = 1 and 
1 = case when EnutriMessageDetails.creation_date >= **[a specified date]**
              then   case when and Urgency.id = 3
                     then 1
                     else 0
                     end
          else 1
          end
```

Edit: Correction.

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Can you explain me what extraly do this case expression?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following to test if it will work  this is to check if its null or not. So then you can react on it.

```
WHERE   Urgency.id LIKE  CASE WHEN Urgency.id IS NULL 
                            THEN Urgency.id
                            ELSE CONCAT('%', Urgency.id, '%')
                            END
```

I dont have a testing environment for mySql so please check if it will work just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want:

```
WHERE (urgency.id = @urgencyid OR @urgencyid IS NULL)
```

or

```
ON (urgency.id = @urgencyid OR @urgencyid IS NULL)
```

So when an ID is given, only data matching the ID will be selected, and if no ID is given, all data will.

The `WHERE` clause will not select any record if the ID does not exist in the table. So the `urgency` table should be inner-joined. If it is outer-joined, the `WHERE` clause turns it into an inner join, as records with ID null will be dismissed. Avoid such pseudo outer joins.

For an inner join it doesn not matter whether to use `WHERE` or `ON`. For an outer join, however, the `WHERE` clause would turn it into an inner join as mentioned, whereas the `ON` clause would still outer-join (with a given ID, either the ID is found or an empty dummy record joined).